# What is the difference between IFP(owl:InverseFunctionalProperty) and FP(owl:FunctionalProperty)?

Tags: semantic-web, owl

I have read W3C documents, but I don't understand why they are different.
I'll give the definitions of them in W3C documents:

- [FP (owl:FunctionalProperty)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-ref-20040210/#FunctionalProperty-def):

  > A functional property is a property that can have only one (unique) value y for each instance x.
- [IFP (owl:InverseFunctionalProperty)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-ref-20040210/#InverseFunctionalProperty-def):

  > If a property is declared to be inverse-functional, then the object of a property statement uniquely determines the subject (some individual).

Here is also a difference: One difference with functional properties is that for inverse-functional properties no additional object-property or datatype-property axiom is required: inverse-functional properties are by definition object properties. You can see these words in the IFP link above.

But I don't understand it, can you give me a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stating that property f is functional means that, for an individual x, there is only one value for f.

So, given:

```
x f p
x f q
```

A reasoner will infer that p and q are the same individual, or the same literal.

Inverse functional means that the inverse of f is functional, i.e.,

```
x f a
y f a
```

Is like

```
a r x
a r y
```

Where r is functional, and the inverse of f. The reasoner can infer that x and y are the same individual (so this time the subjects are inferred to be identical).

This is also the reason for inverse properties to be object properties. If you pick a data property, you cannot have an inverse for it, because you cannot have a literal as subject of a statement.

Comment: @ciferlv Please accept the answer if you deem it correct.

Comment: @Ignazio OK, this is my first time to use stackoverflow, I am a litter unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Ignazio Excuse me, do you know some something about OAEI, Instance Matching or Alignment Format? Can you help me about this question? The link is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502101/how-to-use-alignment-api-to-generate-a-alignment-format-file Thank you.