# How to use Alignment API to generate a Alignment Format file?

Tags: instance, matching, semantic-web, semantics, google-knowledge-graph

I am going to attend the Instance Matching of OAEI, now I need to make my results to Alignment Format. In order to achieve it, I have learned official tutorials.(link:http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial1/index.html).
But there are many differences between the method taught and the method I want. In other words, I can't understand the API.

---

This is my situation:
I have 2 rdf file(person11.rdf and person12.rdf respectively.data link is http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2010/im/index.html, the PR dataset), each file has information of many person. I want to find the coreferent entities, the results must be printed in Alignment Format. I find the results by using SPARQL, but I don't know how to print it in Alignment Format.

---

So, I have three questions:

---

First, if I want to generate a Alignment Format file, is the method taught the only way?

---

Second, can you give me your method(code better) to generate the Alignment Format file? Maybe I am wrong from the beginning, can you give me some suggestions?

---

Third, if you attended OAEI or know something about Instance Matching, can you give me some advice? I want to find the coreferent entities.

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: I guess that the "mentioned method" is the one in tutorial1. It is not the appropriate one since you have to write a program to output the alignment format and this is a command line interface tutorial. In this case, you'd better look at http://alignapi.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tutorial2/index.html

Then, there are basically two ways to do:

The advised one (for several reasons and for participating to OAEI) is to follow these tutorials, to create an empty alignment in it, to create the correspondences from the results of your SPARQL query and to render it. Everything is covered by the tutorials but the part concerning your SPARQL queries. This assumes that you are programming in Java.

The non-advised solution (primarily non advised because you will have to debug your own renderer), is to write, in any programming language that you want a program that output the format (which corresponds to what you cite).

Think about it: how would you expect that the Alignment API knows the results of your SPARQL query? If you come up with a nice solution, contact the API developers, they may integrate it and others could benefit.

Second question: I cannot do better than what is above.

Third question: too general. Read the OAEI results (http://oaei.ontologymatching.org) and look at the code of others.

Good luck!